# Can one clear "encrypt" feature on an ext4 filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, encryption, disk-encryption

One can set the "encrypt" feature on an ext4 filesystem with:

```
tune2fs -O encrypt /dev/device
```

1. How much overhead is with ext4 encryption?
2. If the user no longer needs encryption on this filesystem, is it possible to turn if off? (The man page of `tune2fs` says currently only *setting* this feature is supported.)
3. If the user decides a previously encrypted directory should not be encrypted any more, is it possible to disable encryption on this directory *in-place*, while keeping other encrypted directories intact?

Answer (score 2):

1. Not much, but specifics depend on the encryption used, the CPU etc.
2. `tune2fs` doesn’t support disabling encryption, but it can be done with `debugfs`:

   ```
   debugfs -w -R "feature -encrypt" /dev/...
   ```

   Make sure you run `fsck` before and after, and that you don’t have any encrypted files you care about (`fscrypt status /home` will count the protectors throughout `/home`).
3. Apparently not, you need to copy the files from the encrypted (and unlocked) directory to another, non-encrypted directory.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a strong reason why `tune2fs` doesn't allow flag removal; guess it could be simply due to confusion, since forcefully removing the flag does not actually stop the encryption at all.

Comment: Also both `mke2fs` and `tune2fs` have code to set additional flags (encryption algorithm) in the superblock when enabling the feature; `debugfs` does not and simply ignores the clear flag restrictions. So there is no deliberate implementation of this feature in `debugfs` and *enabling* the flag with it doesn't do the same thing as `mke2fs`/`tune2fs` either.

Comment: About Answer 2: Having to run `fsck` makes that command look really risky. And I assume that command simply disables encryption/decryption processing by removing a flag, but encryption-related metadata (nonces, etc.) are still kept on the filesystem?

Comment: It’s just a precaution. I imagine the flag is only toggled, and all the data remains, but I haven’t checked. (It might be the case that `fsck` clears any encrypted data if the flag is disabled, although I don’t see anything like that in the source code so I suspect it doesn’t.)

Answer (score 0):

Not with `tune2fs`, apparently. So, guess not.

```
# tune2fs -O ^encrypt /dev/loop0
tune2fs 1.45.6 (20-Mar-2020)
Clearing filesystem feature 'encrypt' not supported.
```

Also, note that this flag does not encrypt your filesystem. It merely adds support so you can setup encryption keys and policies *for empty directories* with `e4crypt`. On a filesystem without the `encrypt` feature, `e4crypt` will fail with "Operation not supported" error.

> If the user decides a previously encrypted directory should not be encrypted any more

You have to copy files from encrypted directory to unencrypted one.

Comment: What would be your answer to Question 1, in terms of space overhead? My test shows each encrypted file is 4096-byte larger than an unencrypted one. Do we need to store more than a 16-byte nonce for each file?